# Count Files by Name

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to count files from many sub-folders but the tricky part is that i want to filter them by part of their names. To be more specific, all files have a date at the middle of their names. If I want to just count the files within a specific folder I use this:

```
dir * |%{$_.Name.SubString(7,8)} | group |select name,count|ft -auto
```

And works like a charm. The problem lies that it cannot see more than one folder. Also a second problem is that in the result, I want to see the path name of the grouped counts. I am also testing this:

```
dir -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Write-Host $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }
```

but I cannot implement the date filter from inside the name in this functions. I am also attaching an example of how is the format and how I would like the results.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: You should break it up in parts. Get the files, do the matching, do the counting. one-lines are cool and fun but not always the best solution or easiest to read.

Comment: You should use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1) and [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-5.1) for that. `Select-Object` can [select custom properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). With this set, you can group by that property and return it's count.

Comment: Like `Get-ChildItem * -Recurse | Select-Object -Property name, @{Name="CustomDate";Expression={$_.Name.Split("_")[1]}} | Group-Object -Property CustomDate | Select-Object Name, Count`

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way to count files from many sub-folders but the tricky part is that I want to filter them by part of their names. To be more specific, all files have a date at the middle of their names.

It is not 100% clear to me, if you really want to **filter** them or to **group** them before counting, so I'll show both.

Assuming that this *middle of their names* is, e.g., delimited by `_` this can be achieved the following way:

```
# C:/temp/testFolder/myName_123_folder/text.txt
Get-ChildItem * -Recurse |
    Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name = "CustomDate"; Expression = {$_.Name.Split("_")[1]}} |
    #This is how you would _filter_
    #Where-Object {$_.Custom -eq "123"} |
    Group-Object -Property CustomDate |
    Select-Object Name, Count
```

Don't forget to check if the file name matches this pattern, before splitting. This can be done with a [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1) statement between [`gci`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) and 1. `select`, which checks the file name for your specific pattern.

---

Your question shows also that you wanted to filter for only directories:

> ```
> dir -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ #[...]
> ```

Which is not very efficient.

From the [Docs of `Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1#optional-parameters):

> *-Directory*
>
> Gets directories (folders).
>
> To get only directories, use the `-Directory` parameter and omit the `-File` parameter. To exclude directories, use the `-File` parameter and omit the `-Directory` parameter, or use the `-Attributes` parameter.

This means, the preferred way to search only for Directories is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | % { #[...]
```